# Is it ever possible for these 3 criteria to be true regarding modular matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I am wondering if it is ever possible for the following criteria to be met.

Let $p$ be a prime number and $a$ be some positive integer. All vectors and matrices contain integers mod $p^a$. Let $\mathbf{s}$, $\mathbf{b}$, and $\mathbf{x}$ be such vectors, and $A$ such a matrix.

- $A\mathbf{s}\equiv\mathbf{b}\pmod{p^{a-1}}$
- $\forall \mathbf{y}, A(\mathbf{s}+p^{a-1}\mathbf{y})\not\equiv\mathbf{b}\pmod{p^a}$
- $\exists \mathbf{x}:A\mathbf{x}\equiv\mathbf{b}\pmod{p^a}$

I have tried looking for examples that satisfy all three criteria, but have not found any. I also haven't found any way that these three statements contradict each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make this happen in one dimension:
$$\begin{cases}
    3\cdot3 \equiv 0 \pmod 9 \\
     \forall y,\; 3(3 + 9y) \not\equiv 0 \pmod {27} \\
    3\cdot0 \equiv 0 \pmod {27}
\end{cases}$$
Here, $p = a = A = s = 3$ and $x = b = 0$.